# SharePoint task list with multiple timeline views

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, 2016, task-list, timeline

I have a SharePoint 2013 Project site and I can have only one timeline to a task list. I want to be able to create multiple timelines tied to different views; may be?

Is there a way to do this?

Also, would like to know if multiple task timeline views are allowed in SharePoint 2016?

Comment: Don't think so, the timeline information is stored on the items themselves (like "show on timeline"), so having more than one timeline would be problematic

Comment: this is wrong info. Multiple timelines are permitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't add `Multiple Timelines` for Task List in SharePoint 2013 / 2016.

---

In SharePoint 2016, the **Multiple Timelines** feature is only available in **Project Center**, not the Task List.

[image]

Check also [Project Server 2016: New and deprecated features compared to Project Server 2013](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37814.project-server-2016-new-and-deprecated-features-compared-to-project-server-2013.aspx)